# Does doc2vec work with multi-class problem with only 1 sample per class?

Tags: nlp, gensim, doc2vec

I have a test sentence (which define a skill, such as "Perform equipment maintenance") and a set of diplomas (10000 different diplomas) with description of the needed skills (=1 paragraph per diploma). My problem consists in finding the diploma closest to the test sentence in terms of semantic similarity.

I thought about creating a doc2vec model (multi-class, 1 class per diploma) in order to transform each diploma in feature vector, then infer vector for the test sentence and calculate cosine similarity with each feature vector. Yet, I only have one sample for each diploma. Will it still work? 
Or do I have to split the sentences of each diploma text in order to obtain several samples for a diploma ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your dataset of "one descriptive paragraph per diploma-type" wouldn't normally be described as a "multi-class" problem. The term "multi-class" more usually describes situations where each item itself has more-than-one class/label applied.

But, your approaches as described might be productive, and the only way to know which is better, for your data & goals, would be to evaluate them (and other variants) against each other.

Specifically:

As you describe, you could train a `Doc2Vec` model on your 10,000 short documents that each describe a different diploma. (This is on the smallish side for `Doc2Vec` training data, but perhaps enough. Using a smaller doc-vector size – say 100 dimensions or fewer – and/or more training `epochs` can sometimes help squeeze better results out of smaller datasets.) You'll now have 10,000 doc-vectors, one for each document/diploma.

Then for any new test document – your skill sentence – you'd calculate another doc-vector. You might do this by using the `gensim` `Doc2Vec` `infer_vector()` method. (Note that especially for short texts, you may want to use far more than default number of `epochs` for this calculation.)

Then, you'd search the model for which of the 1st 10,000 doc-vectors are closest to your new vector – and you might find that the closest match, or one of the top-N closest, is a good fit for what you need.

But, there are some other variants to consider:

- If in fact your diploma-descriptions are all multiple sentences – say dozens or even hundreds of words – while your skill-sentences are shorter – say a handful to dozen or two words – then perhaps the best matches to your test-sentence will be to just a *subset* of the longer-paragraphs. In such a case, it *might* be helpful to initially train the model on smaller fragments of text. For example, if the diploma-docs are each 5 sentences, maybe you train the model to know 50,000 separate doc-vectors. Testing a skill-sentence would then be both finding the top-N nearest matches, *then* looking up which diploma the nearby description-sentence was about.
- If your skill-sentences are numerous, and also available at training time, you could plausibly include them in the model training as well. For example, perhaps in addition to your 10,000 diploma-descriptions, you have another 20,000 skill-sentences. You could let the initial model learn 30,000 doc-vectors. Then, you can look-up the diploma-doc-vectors closest to a skill-doc-vector without using `infer_vector()` at all – just using the skill-doc-vector learned during model-training – but you'd have to filter out other skill-doc-vector results from the `most_similar()` list. (You still have the option of using `infer_vector()` on any new texts that come along, but including more text in the initial training **may** make the overall model more expressive.)
- Rather than simply mapping any probe skill-sentence to the single diploma-paragraph that's closest in `Doc2Vec`-coordinate space, if you already had many human-vetted examples of which-skill-sentences should be associates with which-diploma-paragraphs, you could use a second-step supervised classifier algorithm. That is, you'd only use `Doc2Vec` to create feature-vectors for texts, but learn the "labels" (diploma-types) for texts via another training process. There are many potential classifier algorithms, and they are data-hungry, but with enough data, some might have a better chance of learning irregular shapes in the underlying data, for example when a certain diploma-label should, based on historic examples, cover "more" of the skills-space than a simple text-vector-distance would indicate.